# About the Continuous representative

Tags: sobolev-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Hi everyone  (1) Let $u\in W^{1,\infty}(0,\infty)$ such that $u(x)>0$   **for almost all**  $x\in(0,\infty)$ and let $\bar u$ its continuous representative.
Is It true that $\bar u(x)>0$   **for all** $x\in [0,\infty)$.

(2) Is It true that :  $v\in W^{1,p}(I)$ if and only if $\vert v\vert^p \in W^{1,1}(I)$ ?

(3) Is It true to write that
$W^{1,\infty}(]0,\infty[) \hookrightarrow C([0,\infty[)$ et $W^{1,1}(]0,\infty[) \hookrightarrow C([0,\infty[)$ ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) You should be able to adapt the function $|x|$ to your needs. This function is positive almost everywhere, but not everywhere.

(2) One implication is standard, and the other is false. For a typical fixed nonnegative function $w \in W^{1,1}$, think of all functions $v$ such that $|v|^p = w$. Most of them are quite wild.

(3) It's not clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: I am wondering if the injection $W^{1,\infty}(0,\infty) \subset C(0,\infty)$
is continuous ?

Comment: There are some basic questions - what are $W^{1,\infty}$, $C$, and what do you mean by continuous? Once you include it in the question and write about where you're stuck, it's more likely that you get an actual answer. (otherwise I could just guess)

Comment: Please do you have  ideas about this                         https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4092605/rademachers-theorem